# How to create a new `DataFrame` with values obtained from another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame df1:

```
  |Company Name|Contact| Representatives  |
  | XYZ-Corp   |Adam   | Mark, John, Stacy |
```

I want to create a new dataFrame df2 that looks like this:

```
  | Company Name | Contact  |
  | XYZ-Corp     | Adam     |
  | XYZ-Corp     | Mark     |
  | XYZ-Corp     | John     |
  | XYZ-Corp     | Stacy    |
```

How do I do this?
I want to split the values from the representatives column and add it as new rows.

I can use a double for loop, one to iterate through all the rows and another to iterate through the representative names and add to a new dataFrame. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Company Name', inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df.Contact, df.loc[:,'Representatives'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(-1, drop=True)]).reset_index()
df.rename(columns={0: 'Contact'}, inplace=True)

   Company Name  Contact
0   XYZ-Corp     Adam   
1   XYZ-Corp        Mark
2   XYZ-Corp        John
3   XYZ-Corp      Stacy
```

Comment: This works like a charm, can you please explain the code? I would like to learn how this works.

Comment: It splits the names by ',' and expands the result over one column each. 'Stack' pivots the columns to rows and then concats it below the contacts. The reset_index stuff is mostly to clean up. All commands are detailed in the pandas docs.